# How to explain this file write throughput performance?

Tags: file-io, io, operating-system

In the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIOn1.jpg) below, throughput (KB/sec) is plotted for writing new files of various sizes with different record sizes.  File sizes vary from 64KB to 4GB. Record sizes vary from 4KB to 16MB. The file and record sizes are the two horizontal axis and the throughput is plotted on the vertical axis.
I need to understand the causes of the following two observations:

(1) Why are there 2 plateaus: one plateau: file size 128KB to 8MB, another from 64MB to 1GB ?

(2) Why are there 2 peaks (sweet spots) in the range of file-size 256KB and 2MB ?

System has 8GB RAM. I am sure a lot of other parameters shall be required to explain it properly, but still can any probable inference be drawn from the plot ?

[image: File write throughput]

Answer (score 1):

I would be very suspicious about the following factors:

1. Other processes interfering
2. Throughput results are volatile. This is what I would suspect first. What was your measurement methodology?

If I were to perform such a measurement, I would try the following:

- Measure throughput for each scenario multiple times either rebooting the system in between or running some "clean-up" process to make sure one test run doesn't interfere with another one.
- Try to select scenarios in a random pattern.
- Having multiple results for each scenario, throw away the outliers on both ends (or on the slow end) and take an average (or median) of the rest.

Comment: Sure, you are right. But anyways tats not the way I have done. Rather I have used a benchmark tool called IOZone. Anyways, I see a definite pattern emerging from it eg: notice a sudden drop in throughput for files of size greater than 1 GB. That maybe due to direct write to disks.